# Change sysout to String

Tags: java

please for help
I need retrurn in 'String dst;' the same result as console 

e.g. input `txt = "aabbc";` which gives 
 `return dst = "a2b2c1"`

```
public String compres(String txt) {

        String dst = "";
        char character;
        int count;

        for (int i = 0; i < txt.length(); i++) {
            character = txt.charAt(i);
            count = 1;
            while (i < txt.length() - 1 && txt.charAt(i + 1) == character) {
                count++;
                i++;
            }
            System.out.print(character);
            System.out.print(count);
        }
        return dst;
}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem with your code?

Comment: The question is too unclear to respond on it

Comment: Consider using a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) of Character to Integer.  When you encounter a new character, add it to the map with an integer value of 1.  When you see an existing character, increment the integer associated with it.  Then iterate over each entry in the map, and add the character/count pairing to the String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `StringBuilder`.

```
public String compres(String txt) {

        StringBuilder dst = new StringBuilder();
        char character;
        int count;

        for (int i = 0; i < txt.length(); i++) {
            character = txt.charAt(i);
            count = 1;
            while (i < txt.length() - 1 && txt.charAt(i + 1) == character) {
                count++;
                i++;
            }
            System.out.print(character);
            System.out.print(count);
            dst.append(character).append(count);
        }

        return dst.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

today my mate gave me easiest sollution i need add only in my loop:

dst += character + "" + count;

instead of double sysout